# Android Bluetooth low energy pairing show/hide Pin already loaded dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth

[image]

I am trying to write a simple android app that pairs to an nrf52 device(Bluetooth LOW ENERGY, not classic bluetooth). I would like the above image to pop up( I got this image from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

But I am actually getting following image when I try to create bond/pair, how to make the above image show up instead of the below one? Or how do I setpin without any android prompt/notification coming up?

[image]

Comment: Hi Liu, could you post your BLe connect code ? When I try to connect a BLe device, I don't need to pair/pin device.

Comment: I want to pair because our device require BLE encryption. (You know, things we don't want people to sniff)

Comment: i think what I need is having the target device (nrf52) enable bluetooth security 4.2 feature, displayYesNo, using Numeric Comparison - Where a 6 digit number is shown on both devices and user is asked to confirm is they are the same. Used when both devices has display and capable of entering Yes/No.

Comment: Yep, I think you are right. My BLE deivce doesn't require BLE encryption  so I had never seen the pin dialog. Do you achieve the 'Pair dialog' now ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it is not something you can set on the android app. On the target device you need to make sure Bluetooth 4.2 is enabled, and set pairing option with displayYesNo. Take a look at https://www.rigado.com/inexpensive-secure-ble-devices/

So now on my Google pixel 7.1.2, I will get a notification when I try to pair my target device, and if I click on the notification the 6 digit comfirmation screen would show up, and I can click "pair" or "cancel". But if your android phone is too old, it would fall back to asking you to enter 6 digit pins.